# having problem with immutable state in ngrx

Tags: angular, state, ngrx, immutability

im new to ngrx. trying to make the immutable state work, but it doesnt seem to work for me.

i have a reducer here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/brewbrut?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstate%2Fbreweries.reducer.ts

the breweryDetails should return a new array (state), with the filtered result. if i click on a brewery, than go back, or click on the link which navigates back to breweries list, the state is still filtered.

here is the stackblitz: https://brewbrut.stackblitz.io/

here is the reducer:

```
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { IBrewery } from "../definitions/brewery.definition";
import {
  retrievedBreweries,
  listAllBreweries,
  breweryDetails
} from "./breweries.actions";

export const initialState: ReadonlyArray<IBrewery> = [];
export const breweriesReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(retrievedBreweries, (state, { breweries }) => [...state, ...breweries]),
  on(listAllBreweries, state => state),
  on(breweryDetails, (state, { breweryId }) =>
    state.filter(brewery => brewery.id === breweryId)
  )
);
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Comment: @Celsiuss i have added the reducers code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated your code,

Actually, your code works fine without any mutation,

you just clear all Breweries when you select some brewery

In this case, you should create a separate property in store for the selected Brewery

So I changed your AppState, I have created one property for All brews stuff that includes
`breweries` and `selected` .
Now it looks like:

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from "@ngrx/store";
import { IBrewery } from "../definitions/brewery.definition";
import { breweriesReducer } from "./breweries.reducer";

export interface AppState {
  brews: Brews;
}
export interface Brews {
  breweries: ReadonlyArray<IBrewery>;
  selected: IBrewery;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
  brews: breweriesReducer
};
```

Also in app.module changed main reducer

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoreModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Also I changed a little bit your reducer:

```
import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { IBrewery } from "../definitions/brewery.definition";
import { retrievedBreweries, breweryDetails } from "./breweries.actions";

export const initialState = {
  breweries: [],
  selected: null
};
export const breweriesReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(retrievedBreweries, (state, { breweries }) => ({
    ...state,
    breweries
  })),
  on(breweryDetails, (state, { breweryId }) => ({
    ...state,
    selected: [...state.breweries].filter(brewery => brewery.id === breweryId)
  }))
);
```

And instead of your selectors I am using a simple arrow function (what can be easier) in BreweriesComponent and BreweryComponent:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.breweries$ = this.store
      .select(s => s.brews.breweries)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$));
  }
```

Here you can find the full (edited) project:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/brewbrut-envssk?file=src/app/state/breweries.reducer.ts